# Knockout text - background image cut by viewport width - font-size 100vh

Tags: html, css

I want to animate text by using negative `translate-x` on scroll with a really huge text, so huge it occupies the whole viewport in height and is exceeding the viewport width. The effect I want to achieve is to have a static image which gets revealed through animated text *(gif added on the bottom)*.

My problem is that the `background-image` always get cut off by the size of the visible viewport, which results in invisible text after the text get translated to the left.

Here is an code example:
*(example is reduced to 50vh to get two variants on screen for demo)*
https://stackblitz.com/edit/web-platform-jcfzh1?file=styles.css

If you scroll horizontally you will see that you are not able to read the full content - *"Test"* on the text with `background-image: url();`, but can read the full text on the second one with `color: green;`

[image]

```
    <main>
      <p class="text-clipped">Test</p>
      <p class="text-colored">Test</p>
    </main>
```

```
body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: system-ui, sans-serif;
  color: black;
  background-color: white;
}

.text-clipped {
  font: bolder 50vh 'Alfa Slab One';
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0;
  background: url('https://rpsthecoder.github.io/img-repo/Taitō%20by%20Jezael%20Melgoza.jpg');
  background-size: contain;
  background-clip: text;
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  color: transparent;
}

.text-colored {
  margin-top: 0px;
  font: bolder 50vh 'Alfa Slab One';
  text-align: center;
  color: green;
}
```

**Goal:**
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just add

```
.text-clipped {
   .....
   width: min-content;
}
```

It also work

```
.text-clipped {
   .....
   width: max-content;
}
```

and this

```
.text-clipped {
   .....
   width: fit-content;
}
```

Comment: Here is a working implementation with react and tailwind.
https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-fmdjew?file=pages%2Findex.tsx

Thank you!